# Update sub document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, document

Right now I am working on MongoDB in ASP.NET and just gone through an article in which it has taken a blog post example and mentioned the following steps to update comments (sub document).

1. The blog was taken a main document
2. Comments were taken as sub document and posted along with main document
3. When we need to insert a new comment to a particular blog, we are getting the existing blog document, adding new comment (sub document) in front-end and again updating the blog document with blog ID.

If it is the case, let us take very popular blog scenario where thousands of comments were posted to a blog. If any new comment has to be posted, we need to get all the existing comments from DB server to Web server as a result it will increase network traffic.

Is this general scenario or is there any alternative way to add new content to sub document? Means, I need a functionality which should just insert new values in existing document.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB supports a "push" command. The [push command](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24push) will append an item to an existing array.

Answer (score 0):

There is a **$push** operator which is used to append the specified value to an array. Suppose we have the following schema for blog post. There are already two comments in the post and if you want to add another comment to the post you can use the $push operator. I have written a sample code to insert a comment to the below schema in node but you can use the the logic in any .NET too

`{
        "_id" : ObjectId("55d58d05471d5cc42aaaef1b"),
        "title" : "How to drop a collection in MongoDB?",
        "author" : "dp123",
        "body" : "body part goes ........!!!",
        "permalink" : "How_to_drop_a_collection_in_MongoDB",
        "tags" : [
                "MongoDB",
                "Mongod",
                "mongo"
        ],
        "comments" : [
                {
                        "author" : "DP",
                        "body" : "awesome ......",
                        "email" : "dp@tektak.com"
                },
                {
                        "author" : "John",
                        "body" : "This article is really useful for me. I am not getting solution since last few week but finally I got it. Thank you very much!!!",
                        "email" : "john@gmail.com"
                }
        ],
        "date" : ISODate("2015-08-20T08:17:09.541Z")
}`

```
 **The code snippet is given below:**





   var comment = {'author': name, 'body': body};
   if (email != "") {
        comment['email'] = email;
    }

   var query ={'permalink': permalink};
   var operation ={'$push':{'comments': comment}};
   db.collection('posts').update(query, operation, function (err, updated){
        console.log("Successfully added the comment!!!");            
  });
```

We can get the detailed about the $push at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/